# How to use local variables inside a QUERY in Terraform

Tags: syntax, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, kql, azure-sentinel

I am trying to deploy an alert rule for sentinel solution using Terraform. I use `sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled` resource from Azure provider and has a list of values hardcoded in the query of the alert rule.

Since the elements in the list can be changed time to time, I want to take the list out from the query and refer to it using a variable (local variable should be ideal). I need to know the support in Terraform for me to achieve this.

current alert rule resource:

```
resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "alert_rule_scheduled" {
  name                       = some_name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = some_log_analytics_workspace_id
  display_name               = some_.display_name
  description                = some_description

  enabled                    = true
  severity                   = "Low"

  query                      = <<QUERY
let someList = dynamic([element1,element2,element3,...])
.
.[query goes on]
.
QUERY

  query_frequency            = "PT1H"
  query_period               = "PT1H"

  trigger_operator           = "GreaterThan
  trigger_threshold          = 0
  suppression_enabled        = false
  tactics                    = ["IP"]
  
}
```

I want to refactor the above code for something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "alert_rule_scheduled" {
  name                       = some_name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = some_log_analytics_workspace_id
  display_name               = some_.display_name
  description                = some_description

  enabled                    = true
  severity                   = "Low"

  query                      = <<QUERY
let someList = dynamic(${local.my_list_variable})
.
.[query goes on]
.
QUERY

  query_frequency            = "PT1H"
  query_period               = "PT1H"

  trigger_operator           = "GreaterThan
  trigger_threshold          = 0
  suppression_enabled        = false
  tactics                    = ["IP"]
  
}

locals {
  my_list_variable = [element1,element2,element3,...]
}
```

Using `$local.my_list_variable` gives the error `Invalid template interpolation value`.

I was wondering whether we can do this kind of thing in Terraform and if there is, the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Have you tried only `local.my_list_variable` without curly brackets and the dollar sign?

Comment: @MarkoE Thank you for your comment. Then it treats like a string part of the query. I figured that wont work either.

Comment: `my_list_variable = [element1,element2,element3,...]` this is not even a valid TF code. Thus its not clear what you are trying to achieve. Also its not possible to get the error that you are reporting, because, well, your TF is incorrect to start with.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the comment. can you please explain further why it is not valid code, for example cannot i have a TF local variable as locals { fruits = ["Apple","Banana","Mango"]} ? if not, how should I declare it.

Comment: `fruits = ["Apple","Banana","Mango"]` is correct, but `my_list_variable = [element1,element2,element3,...]` is not. Your current code leads me to believe that in other areas of your actual code you also have some syntax errors, leading to your issues.

Comment: @Marcin oh that was just a sample. my actual code has a huge list of domain names that is why i put a dummy like `element1` and `...`. Hope that lead to your thoughts of my code is incorrect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem here is you are attempting string interpolation on a `list` type, which generally does not work in most languages without being converted to a `string`. However, you actually meant to cast the variable as a `string` and not a `list` anyway because it should be directly evaluated as a Terraform `string` type:

```
locals {
  my_list_variable = "[element1,element2,element3,...]"
}
```

and then within your HEREDOC:

```
let someList = dynamic(${local.my_list_variable})
```

will render as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. this was exactly i was looking for and it worked. Thanks for the insightful explanation.